# Android App to Send Images Via Email

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Ok once again, I am in way over my head here while learning android. After finally developing my simple little app, I am trying to use some of the benefits of having a native app.

So, project one, make a page which can send images via email (either from the gallery or camera)

Essentially its a select and send via email, but I don't even know where to start.

I found some code that somebody else was asking about at;
[Android App Take/ Email Photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231988/android-app-take-email-photo)

I tried this, but get all sorts of errors from eclipse, replating to **downloadedPic** section.

If somebody could please take a look and advise me on the best way to do this, that would be amazing. As usual sorry for my beginers stupidity, but I guess everyone has to learn somewhere

**THIS IS MY .JAVA AT PRESENT**

```
public class Photos extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photos);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_photos, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**THIS IS MY .XML AT PRESENT**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please chose the options below to select and upload photos into the 
    DCC for the selected project..."
    tools:context=".Photos"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it should be attachment or body area ?

Comment: attachment please... :) if possible...

Comment: also if you could explain what each section does in the code that would be amazing !

Comment: only attachment possible beacuse body will not accept any image.you should wait i mad for you

Comment: see i have upload code and get back to me how it is ?

Comment: Wondering if you succeeded? Did you release the app in the app store? I am looking for exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First what should you do is get the image storage path by using the file,

```
 File *photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/"+getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/Fault", imagename+".png");
```

Then Convert that file path in to `Uri`

```
Uri imageuri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
```

Finally send it the image via email using your `imageuri`

```
Intent send_report = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                        send_report.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ email_emailid}); 
                                        send_report.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, email_subject);
                                        send_report.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageuri);
                                        send_report.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, email_body);  
                                        send_report.setType("text/plain");
                                        send_report.setType("image/png");
                                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(send_report, "Choose an Email client"), 77);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I know the intent falls within the .java of the page, but what about the URI and the FILE?

Comment: Yes i have used this code its working thank you Vino this great post ...................

Answer (score 1):

**Get Your Image First :**

```
 // Get Image form mnt/sdcard/YOUR_FLODER/my_image.png    
    ImageView my_Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_Image);    
    Imagepath="/sdcard/YOUR_FLODER/"+my_iamge+".png";
     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Imagepath);
```

**Fetch mail address:**

```
// This Will fetch merchant's Email id from Deivce.
    Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+

    AccountManager manager =(AccountManager)getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
    //Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext()).getAccounts();
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccounts();

    for (Account account : accounts) 
    {
        if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) 
        {
             possibleEmail = account.name;
        }
    }
```

**Send Click Event :**

```
        Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("image/png");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC,new String[]{possibleEmail});  
        i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Mail With Image attachment");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i2, "Send Email..."));
```

**At The End Photos.java**

```
public class Photos extends Activity
{
     @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.Activity_Photos);

          // your image fetching code
          // fetch mail code 
          // write button click event 
               // put intent code in click event

    }
}
```

**So Hope Now you Get Full Code.**

Comment: Ok, sorry to be a pain, but now I am even more confused, is there any chance you could provide the codes for the .jave and .xml page for me, just two serperate codes...

Comment: **My activity names are**SRC > Photos.Java and Layout > Activity_Photos.xml

Sorry to be such a noob!!!

Comment: hmm... I hate being a total idiot... still no luck :( perhaps I should just let someone jump on my PC with teamviewer to fix this for me haha...

Comment: SO YOU WANT THAT I SEND YOU A MAIL ?

Comment: haspden@topspeedsupport.co.uk :(

Comment: check your mail id. now don't tell me that its not working .:)