# App to share a screenshot via email with preset recipient, subject, and body text?

Tags: android, email, share, attachment

I need to regularly send screenshots from my phone to the same email address, with the same subject line, and the same body text.

Ideally, I'd use the "share" option that appears whenever you take a screenshot, share it to a bespoke app, and that app would attach the screenshot to an email already drafted and ready to send.

I have not written an app before.

I found this code already which seems to cover some of the fundamentals:-

[Android App to Send Images Via Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230739/android-app-to-send-images-via-email)

I need to find out the basics about how to create the app, and how to add it to the "share" options.

Thanks a lot for any help...

Answer (score 0):

[Android Share Something with example](https://www.androidcode.ninja/android-share-intent-example/)

Try this code for sharing image, it will works :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.setType("application/image");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emails@email.com");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("**storage location**"));
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

just put storage location with extension in Uri.parse(" ");

Comment: Hi there - thanks a lot for the reply, but I think that's for something a bit different. If I understand correctly, that's for sharing an image from within my app. I want to share an image _to_ my app, from the screenshot capture page, and have the app generate and send the proforma email with the image attached.